# How to convert the matrix row to zeros except the last row in r

Tags: r, matrix

Assume that I have a matrix `x`. I would like to convert all its entries to zeros except the last row. For example, if `x` is as follows:

```
x <- matrix(3,11,11)
```

I would like to convert all the rows to zero except the last row, `x[11,]`.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also be done with negative indexing:

```
x[-nrow(x), ] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just index the rows of your matrix with `1:(nrow(x)-1)` and assign them the value 0:

```
 x[1:(nrow(x)-1),] <- 0
```